# Remove a motive in the column names (in R)

Tags: r, multiple-columns, names

I have colnames that start with E_x_b_E_uniqueNumber.
I would like to remove b_E_ motive from each column.

I have tried this apporach but it removes everything:

`colnames (data) <- sub('(.*)_.*', '', colnames(data))`

Comment: Are you asking specifically for `b_E_` or the two characters (words) and two underscores after the first two?

Comment: Why not just simply `gsub('_b_E', '', 'E_x_b_E_uniqueNumber')`?